# Find which term is repeated in a string, when given a known number of N occurrences in the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

There is any way to do the following, without using brute force or something like that?

```
str = "abbcccddddefefef"
N = 3
repeated_term = func(str,N)

print(repeated_term )
> ['c','ef']


N = 2
term = func(str,N)

print(term)   
> ['b', 'dd', 'fe']    # Thanks to @blhsing for the correction!
```

and so on...

Comment: What does `N` represent in `func(str, N)`?

Comment: @OmariCelestine hi omari, sorry i didn't write this. N is the the number occurrences that we are looking for. for example, looking for term that has exactly 2  occurrences in the string

Comment: @blhsing hi, I clicked it. I would like to know if you can briefly explain me what the expression you wrote is doing, it will help me greatly. Thank you and Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), which supports variable-width lookbehind patterns, to use a regex that finds sequences that are repeated exactly N - 1 times:

```
import regex
def func(s, N):
    return regex.findall(r'(?=(.+?)(?:\1){%d}(?!\1))(?<!\1)' % (N - 1), s)
```

so that:

```
func("abbcccddddefefef", 3)
```

returns:

```
['c', 'ef']
```

and that:

```
func("abbcccddddefefef", 2)
```

returns:

```
['b', 'dd', 'fe']
```

Note that your expected output for N=2 is incorrect because `'dd'` and `'fe'` both also occur exactly 2 times.

Comment: Couldn't you just check that the captured group is repeated `N-1` times, but not `N` times?

Comment: @blhsing Wow thanks! I did not expect such a detailed answer so fast :)
I do not know Regex well, if you can briefly explain what makes the phrase you wrote it will help me greatly.
Thank you and Have a nice day!
And thanks for the correction regarding N = 2. You're right and I did not notice it.